# Get floatnum with different precision

Tags: floating-point, scheme, racket, precision

JavaScript has `toFixed` function that acts like this:

```
3.14159265359.toFixed(4)
> "3.1415"
```

Is there any similar one in Racket?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`~r`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/strings.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fformat..rkt%29._~7er%29%29) from the [`racket/format`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/strings.html#%28part._format%29) module:

```
> (require racket/format)
> (~r pi #:precision 4)
"3.1416"
```